# La locuzione "armi e bagagli" può avere un uso avverbiale?

Tags: word-usage, grammar

Nel romanzo *Un sabato, con gli amici* di Andrea Camilleri ho letto la frase seguente:

> «Ti va bene se arrivo domani pomeriggio *armi e bagagli*?»

Non conoscevo l'espressione "armi e bagagli", quindi ne ho cercato informazioni nei dizionari. Nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/bagaglio) ho trovato

> **bagàglio**
>
> Tutto ciò che viene trasportato al seguito di truppe in marcia o in guerra (oltre la dotazione personale, armi, zaino, tascapane, ecc.); è sinon. di *salmerie*. Con questo sign. è usato spec. nella locuz. *armi e bagagli*: *furono fatti prigionieri con armi e bagagli*; anche in senso fig., tutte le proprie robe, tutto ciò che uno si porta dietro: *andarsene, sloggiare con armi e bagagli; abbiamo perso armi e bagagli*.

Anche in [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/definizione/bagaglio) si trova

> Locuzione: **Armi e b.** tutto ciò che uno possiede: Esempio: sloggiare con armi e b.

Non ho nessun problema a capire il significato di questa espressione. Quello che non mi è chiaro è l'uso che se ne fa. Negli esempi dei dizionari sembra avere valore di sintagma nominale, invece nel brano di Camilleri sembra avere un uso avverbiale. È così? Qualcuno può aiutarmi a chiarire i miei dubbi a riguardo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Armi e bagagli](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/armi-e-bagagli):

> - loc.s.f.pl. tutto ciò che una persona possiede: prendere armi e bagagli e partire.

L'uso dell'espressione è solitamente nominale: fare/prendere/partire (con) armi e bagagli.

L'uso avverbiale che ne fa Camilleri non è insolito:

- È arrivato a casa mia un mio amico, armi e bagagli, e si fermerà per un mese.
- Me ne andrei, armi e bagagli, a vivere all'estero.

> - «Spero solo di incassare in un modo o nell'altro; e sarà proprio stasera, o va fuori, la vagabonda, ***armi e bagagli***». [Il vicario di Wakefield](https://books.google.it/books?id=4kr3VOpXFO4C&pg=PA152&dq=%22armi%20e%20bagagli%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0CD8Q6AEwBmoVChMIpayCvPCUxgIViFgsCh1-2QM1#v=onepage&q=%22armi%20e%20bagagli%22&f=false).
> - «A domare le loro resistenze il primo ad intromettersi fu monsignor Cioja16, il 12 marzo; fallito il suo tentativo, intervennero quindi, l'indomani, i tre canonici della Basilica che, ***armi e bagagli***, erano passati incondizionatamente dallA parte dei Francesi.» [I romani e la nascita dei re di Roma](https://books.google.it/books?id=_3xGqUIiG1IC&pg=PA173&dq=%22armi%20e%20bagagli%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0CCAQ6AEwATgKahUKEwjm8q-B8ZTGAhXLjSwKHTA8ABY#v=onepage&q=%22armi%20e%20bagagli%22&f=false)
> - «Quando però ci fu il collasso dell'esercito italiano, gli ex occupanti passarono ***armi e bagagli*** nella nostra Resistenza diventando quindi degli alleati. In seguito ho partecipato ad una dura lotta contro i tedeschi e contro gli inglesi. Churchill ...» [Xenakis](https://books.google.it/books?id=Qe-Qcy6c9t8C&pg=PA9&dq=%22armi%20e%20bagagli%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0CD0Q6AEwBjgUahUKEwjWo5eF9JTGAhUBmiwKHWoGA-c#v=onepage&q=%22armi%20e%20bagagli%22&f=false)